# DropDownListfor in EditorTemplates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Am creating a EditorTemplate for Boolean fields to have Yes no DropDown and below is my code

```
@model Nullable<bool>

@{
    var listItems = new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "true", Text = "Yes" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "false", Text = "No" }
    };

}

    @Html.DropDownListFor( ????, listItems,"")
```

Where i want to load the Drop-down with previously selected item which is available in Model which can be true or false

From My view i will be getting true or false in **Model** Property to this template. How can i use DropDownfor as it accepts linq in 1st paramtere ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can either use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, listItems, "")
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownList("", listItems, "")
```

Comment: @Zadavsky m=>m will not retail the already selected value. while loading i need to load the previously selected item(which may be true or false